# Change CSS class based on the percent value

Tags: jquery, html, clone, attr

[Here's the latest JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CzZxf/2/).

HTML:

```
<table id="math-table">
    <tr>
           <td><input type="text" id="A1" name="A" value=""></td>
           <td><input type="text" id="B1" name="B" value=""></td>
           <td><input type="text" id="C1" name="C" readonly="readonly" tabIndex="-1" value=""></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$("#math-table input").live("keyup", function(){
var id = this.id.match(/\d+/);
$("#C"+id).val( Math.round (($("#A"+id).val() / $("#B"+id).val()) * 100) + "%"  );

$('#A'+id).attr('value', $('#A'+id).val());  
$('#B'+id).attr('value', $('#B'+id).val());  
$('#C'+id).attr('value', $('#C'+id).val());  
});

var uniqueIds = $("#math-table tr").length;
$("#math-table input[id^='B']").live("change", function(){
var $thisRow = $(this).closest("tr"),
$clone = $thisRow.clone(),             // Clone row
$inputs = $clone.find("input").val("");// Reset values, return all inputs
uniqueIds++; //Increment ID
$inputs[0].id = "A" + uniqueIds;
$inputs[1].id = "B" + uniqueIds;
$inputs[2].id = "C" + uniqueIds;
$thisRow.after($clone);                    
});
```

You can see that A/B = C%  Pretty simple. How would I add a different CSS class to only C based on a certain %?

Red 1-33%

Green 34-66%

Blue  67-100%

Comment: By the way, you really ought to put in a trap for divide-by-zero results.

Comment: By not putting the code in the question, it's clear that you don't care whether this ever benefits anyone else.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll add it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CzZxf/13/

I added a variable `percent` and set the background color based on that like this:

```
  if(percent>0 && percent<34)
    $('#C'+id).addClass("red");
if(percent>33 && percent<67)
    $('#C'+id).addClass("green");
if(percent>67)
    $('#C'+id).addClass("blue");
```

**EDIT**: I updated the script to remove the class from the clone. Add this

```
$inputs = $clone.find("input").val("").removeClass();
```

Comment: I like and understand this, however.. on the clone the previous added class also gets cloned. Any way to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `addClass , removeClass` functions to change. Like below:

> $(".first").addClass("second") // add a class
>
> $(".first").removeClass("second")  // remove a class

Just take the C value inside a variable and change class according to % you want by applying if/else

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a simple if - else if or switch statement based on C value.
Just store the C value inside a variable and make your test.

Simply use addClass (http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) or removeClass (http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 0):

Do it the most obvious way:

```
var num = Math.round(($("#A" + id).val() / $("#B" + id).val()) * 100);
$("#C" + id).val(num + "%");
if (num >= 0 && num <= 33) {
    var cname = "alpha";
} else if (num > 33 && num <= 66) {
    var cname = "beta";
} else if (num > 66 && num <= 100) {
    var cname = "gamma";
}
$('#C').removeClass().addClass(cname);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/CzZxf/7/

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/CzZxf/5/

It's not exactly using classes, but it should give you enough to customize it to fit your needs:

```
$("#math-table input").live("keyup", function(){
    var id = this.id.match(/\d+/);
    var result = Math.round (($("#A"+id).val() / $("#B"+id).val()) * 100);
    var result_color = (result >=1 && result < 34) ? 'red' : (result >=34 && result < 67) ? 'green' : 'blue';

    $("#C"+id).val( result + "%"  ).css('color', result_color);

    $('#A'+id).attr('value', $('#A'+id).val());  
    $('#B'+id).attr('value', $('#B'+id).val());  
    $('#C'+id).attr('value', $('#C'+id).val());  
});

var uniqueIds = $("#math-table tr").length;
$("#math-table input[id^='B']").live("change", function(){
    var $thisRow = $(this).closest("tr"),
    $clone = $thisRow.clone(),             // Clone row
    $inputs = $clone.find("input").val("");// Reset values, return all inputs
    uniqueIds++; //Increment ID
    $inputs[0].id = "A" + uniqueIds;
    $inputs[1].id = "B" + uniqueIds;
    $inputs[2].id = "C" + uniqueIds;
    //$inputs.eq(0).focus();                     
    $thisRow.after($clone);                    
});
```